# Change Windows special folders location programmatically

Tags: c#, windows

How do I change the windows special folders location? (On Win7, Preferably using C#).
Basically trying to do what the windows interface allows us to do, but programmatically. (See image) On top of changing the location it should also move any existing contents.

Searched around a bit, Apparently SHSetKnownFolderPath does not work with 32 bit apps (see the [comments at the end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shsetknownfolderpath))

[image]

Comment: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff934858.aspx

Comment: I believe, I found what you need: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976027 CODE!!!

Comment: Three years later, still no good answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to change registry entries. They should be at the following spots:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
```

Comment: Although, how will Windows react should you change registry? You may need to force logout? This will give you better idea how to do it properly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff934858.aspx

Comment: @ T.S. - Did you mean, as soon as i change the registry for it to be in effect i might need to logout / restart?

Comment: @Tim - Modifying the reg entries, will I see the 32 bit apps issue mentioned in the documentation link above?

Comment: This won't actually move the documents though. And that's going to be *fun* because you'll need to handle files being open and stuff. Just like when you copy files in Explorer. This is pretty involved.

Comment: This is why using Win Api is the right way, it does what you command from the UI in windows. Although, some operations can be safely done in registry, this one probably not one of them because that stuff constantly in use. If you do in UI, you will probably see some blinking - the windows resetting itself

Comment: Any workaround such that I can use the Win api SHSetKnownFolderPath which will work for 32 bit apps?

Comment: I don't have idea at this time.

Comment: This is wrong. Read my CodeProject article about why and what is the right solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878605/Getting-All-Special-Folders-in-NET

Comment: @RayKoopa your "solution" does not solve the problem, though, which is redefining those paths not just retrieving them.

Comment: @VillasV I can't quite follow your comment. You can read and change and initialize the paths.

Comment: @RayKoopa ah, the NuGet package yes. Not the code on your link, though.

Comment: @VillasV Yes, the code in the article just discusses one aspect of the task since the other parts are pretty self-explaining if you know one :)

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft:

Windows 7 shell libraries are common stores of user-defined locations. Applications can use these libraries to manage user content. However, because libraries are not file system locations, you may have to update some applications to work with shell libraries as if they were folders.

The sample projects that are provided in this download package show how you can programmatically manipulate Windows 7 shell libraries by using Visual C++, Visual C#, or Visual Basic .NET. In these sample projects, you can find basic steps about how to create, open, delete, rename, and manage shell libraries. These sample projects also show how you can add, remove, and list folders in a shell library.

support.microsoft.com/kb/976027

Comment: this looks like it could help. Thanks will have a look.

Comment: For those who might be interested, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx