# C# Change Windows "Special Folders"

Tags: c#, filesystems

I'm trying to change the path for a few windows "special folders" to another drive. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153502/change-windows-special-folders-location-programmatically) however it doesn't just quite explain enough for me. Changing the registry keys isn't what I'm looking for, as files are not copied nor does it check if a file is in use.

I can call the path of e.g. System32 via

```
             Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special folders are stored in the registry.

There is no WinAPI to change them, as I know.

The only way is to handle the registry.

The only way to change them is to change the registry values.

And after:

- Reboot the machine,
- Or at least close the session and reopen it,
- Or perhaps in a hard way kill the `explorer.exe` process and run it again, using the Task Explorer or any Tasker.

All system tweaker apps allowing to do that, do that in this way, I suppose.

[Change Windows special folders location programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153502/change-windows-special-folders-location-programmatically)

Comment: Alright, got it! I'll do a foreach loop or something similar to copy the files then.